# Añadir una subconsulta con campo clave extraido de consulta primaria

Tags: mysql, woocommerce

Es un poco complejo a mi entender con que a ver si lo explico bien.

Estoy generando una tabla con algunos datos de compras realizadas con woocommerce.

Como sabréis, el nombre del campo se guarda en una celda y su valor en otra de modo que postmeta.meta_key es el nombre del campo y meta_value es el valor que se le dió a ese campo.

eso lo extraigo en el SELECT con:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_postmeta.meta_key = "_billing_first_name", meta_value, NULL)) AS nombre,
```

Como los datos que me interesan son solo de aquellas compras que fueron correctamente pagadas, hago unos inner join para extraer de otra tabla de woocommerce los id de aquellas compras que fueron completadas y que además pertenecen a un producto en concreto. Esto lo hago con

```
INNER JOIN basedatos_posts ON basedatos_postmeta.post_id = basedatos_posts.ID 
INNER JOIN basedatos_woocommerce_order_items ON basedatos_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = basedatos_posts.ID 
WHERE basedatos_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_name LIKE "%MIPRODUCTO%" 
AND basedatos_posts.post_type="shop_order" AND basedatos_posts.post_status="wc-completed"
```

Os pongo la consulta entera (que como no soy muy hábil en mysql igual hasta hay margen a simplificarla):

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT basedatos_postmeta.post_id, basedatos_posts.post_date AS fecha,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_postmeta.meta_key = "_billing_first_name", meta_value, NULL)) AS nombre,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_postmeta.meta_key = "_billing_last_name", meta_value, NULL)) AS apellidos,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_postmeta.meta_key = "_billing_state", meta_value, NULL)) AS provincia,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_postmeta.meta_key = "_billing_country", meta_value, NULL)) AS pais,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_type = "coupon", order_item_name, NULL)) AS cupon, 
basedatos_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_name AS navegacion
FROM basedatos_postmeta
INNER JOIN basedatos_posts ON basedatos_postmeta.post_id = basedatos_posts.ID 
INNER JOIN basedatos_woocommerce_order_items ON basedatos_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = basedatos_posts.ID 
WHERE basedatos_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_name LIKE "%MIPRODUCTO-X%" 
AND basedatos_posts.post_type="shop_order" AND basedatos_posts.post_status="wc-completed" 
AND (basedatos_postmeta.meta_key="_billing_first_name" OR basedatos_postmeta.meta_key="_billing_last_name" OR basedatos_postmeta.meta_key="_billing_state" OR basedatos_postmeta.meta_key="_billing_country")
GROUP BY basedatos_posts.ID ORDER BY fecha ASC')
```

Bueno, hasta aquí todo bien y mysql devuelve una tabla de valores pero ahora, por 'exigencias del guión' tuve que crear un formulario mas complejo de compra, con mas campos y que con las variantes de woocommerce no son suficientes (o lo hacen exageradamente complejo todo), por ello usé gravity forms.

En resumen, ahora parte del pedido se guarda en las tablas de woocommerce y las variables y características del producto en las tablas de gravity forms.

Aquí es donde surge el problema porque necesito mostrar en **la misma tabla** además algunos campos que se recogen en gravity forms.

En gravity forms, la tabla que recoge cada detalle de compra, su estructura es esencialmente esta:

entry_id | meta_key | meta value

111 |woocommerce-form|900

111 | talla_camiseta | XL

111 | color_camiseta | negro

111 | marca_camiseta | fruit of the loom

--------------- #OTRO PEDIDO-------------------

110 |woocommerce-form|902

110 | talla_camiseta | M

110 | color_camiseta | blanco

110 | marca_camiseta | revel

Como veis, el único campo que une los registros de gravity_forms con el pedido de woocommerce es la primera línea donde **meta_key** identifica con el campo woocommerce-form y **meta_value** el numero de pedido (que si veis el ejemplo, sería el valor 900).

Este valor, para cada pedido, sabría sacarlo si desde la primera consulta, que puse arriba extrayese el numero de pedido (basedatos_postmeta.post_id) y así, con una una segunda consulta que sería algo así:

`SELECT entry_id AS detalles 
FROM basedatos_gf_entry_meta
WHERE basedatos_gf_entry_meta.meta_value = basedatos_postmeta.post_id`

Así diferenciamos el valor de entry_id para cada pedido, con lo que extraer el resto de detalles/campos del pedido en cuestión sería posible.

Sacar el detalle de esos datos lo he hecho así (en una 3ª consulta que sería dependiente de la anterior):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_gf_entry_meta.meta_key = "11", meta_value, NULL)) AS categoria_gravity_off,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_gf_entry_meta.meta_key = "15", meta_value, NULL)) AS seguro_gravity_off,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_gf_entry_meta.meta_key = "6", meta_value, NULL)) AS acompanantes_gravity_off,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_gf_entry_meta.meta_key = "19", meta_value, NULL)) AS alojamiento_gravity_off,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_gf_entry_meta.meta_key = "16", meta_value, NULL)) AS camiseta_gravity_off,
FROM basedatos_gf_entry_meta
WHERE entry_id=detalles
```

y en el WHERE, el dato: "detalles" se habría sacado como decimos antes.

Como veis, son 3 consultas donde los datos de la primera + los de la ultima me sirven para sacar la tabla que quiero y donde la 2ª consulta es el valor que me sirve para enlazar *datos del cliente y producto* con los *detalles de ese producto*.

Aunar esto en una sola consulta es lo que no se como hacer. He intentado muchas cosas sin dar con ello.

Estoy bloqueado. ¿¿¿Alguien puede ayudarme???

(He editado la pregunta para hacerla, espero, mas comprensible y tras la respuesta de Fly para que se entienda mejor el detalle de lo de la 2ª consulta y que no lo expliqué bien).

Comment: Necesitas hacerlo necesariamente desde una consulta? No puedes procesar los datos desde, php o usar tablas temporales? Ten en cuenta que, aunque logres conseguirlo en una sola consulta, mantener ese código va a ser un horror y créeme si te digo que mienten si dicen que "las especificaciones no van a cambiar" ;)

Comment: Ante todo gracias por responder Fly.

Si, es necesario que sea mediante consulta sql que se actualiza cada vez que se quiere comprobar.

No estoy muy seguro de a qué te refieres con procesar desde php o tablas temporales pero necesito que sea compatible con la API de woocommerce (por el panel de gestión que se tiene luego desde el backend de ese plugin).

Sé que "las especificaciones exactas SI van a cambiar", tanto que para otro producto que hay, los campos de variaciones de gravity cambian (pero mientras funcione la consulta y solo sean esas variaciones, estaría dentro de lo asumible).

Comment: He añadido la segunda consulta, de donde saco los datos extra que necesito de las otras tablas.
Como unir esas 2 consultas supongo que será con JOIN pero no se donde ni como poner las cláusulas WHERE para que funcione.

Comment: Deberías ser más específico en cuanto a que problemas tienes para resolver lo que  planteas. Revisa  el Centro de Ayuda para saber [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: En la consulta del medio pones `WHERE wor8455_gf_entry_meta.meta_value = wor8455_postmeta.post_id`  ¿de donde sale `wor8455_postmeta`? no aparece en ninguna consulta. Por otra parte en, `WHERE entry_id = detalles` es un valor único, podrías hacer una subconsulta``WHERE entry_id = (SELECT entry_id FROM wor8455_gf_entry_meta WHERE...)` ¿no?

Comment: lo de "wor8455_" o "basedatos_" es en realidad el sufijo que se lo cambié aquí para el ejemplo. Supuestamente en la 1º parte de la consulta ya se estaría extrayendo ese valor.

Comment: Lo de hacer la subconsulta, no sabía que se pudiese repetir la cláusula WHERE en una misma consulta. Lo pruebo a ver

Answer (score 0):

Dudo que sea correcto pero lo tengo que poner como respuesta para poder maquetarlo:

```
SELECT
        basedatos_postmeta.post_id, basedatos_posts.post_date AS fecha,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_postmeta.meta_key = "_billing_first_name", meta_value, NULL)) AS nombre,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_postmeta.meta_key = "_billing_last_name", meta_value, NULL)) AS apellidos,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_postmeta.meta_key = "_billing_state", meta_value, NULL)) AS provincia,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_postmeta.meta_key = "_billing_country", meta_value, NULL)) AS pais,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_type = "coupon", order_item_name, NULL)) AS cupon, 
        basedatos_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_name AS navegacion,

        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_gf_entry_meta.meta_key = "11", meta_value, NULL)) AS categoria_gravity_off,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_gf_entry_meta.meta_key = "15", meta_value, NULL)) AS seguro_gravity_off,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_gf_entry_meta.meta_key = "6", meta_value, NULL)) AS acompanantes_gravity_off,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_gf_entry_meta.meta_key = "19", meta_value, NULL)) AS alojamiento_gravity_off,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(basedatos_gf_entry_meta.meta_key = "16", meta_value, NULL)) AS camiseta_gravity_off

FROM basedatos_postmeta
INNER JOIN basedatos_posts ON basedatos_postmeta.post_id = basedatos_posts.ID 
INNER JOIN basedatos_woocommerce_order_items ON basedatos_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = basedatos_posts.ID 
 LEFT JOIN basedatos_gf_entry_meta ON basedatos_gf_entry_meta.entry_id = basedatos_woocommerce_order_items.order_id
WHERE basedatos_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_name LIKE "%MIPRODUCTO-X%" 

AND basedatos_posts.post_type="shop_order" AND basedatos_posts.post_status="wc-completed" 
AND (basedatos_postmeta.meta_key="_billing_first_name" OR basedatos_postmeta.meta_key="_billing_last_name" OR basedatos_postmeta.meta_key="_billing_state" OR basedatos_postmeta.meta_key="_billing_country")
GROUP BY basedatos_posts.ID ORDER BY fecha ASC
```

Creo que sería necesario un ejemplo de la estructura y algunos datos (no todos, claro) para poder probar la consulta, así a ojo es imposible para mi saber si es lo que necesitas.

> Puedes dejar un pequeño ejemplo de la base de datos usando alguna
>   herramienta online como
>   [esta](https://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler), por ejemplo, para facilitar el intercambio de información.

Comment: Intuyo que está casi Fly, y al ver tu reestructuración del código, me ha parecido mas mas claro... de hecho me he dado cuenta de un error que yo he puesto en la explicación que lleva a confusión (y lo voy a editar en la pregunta para que se entienda qué es lo que falta por esclarecer).

Comment: Ya está editada la pregunta y aclaro lo de la consulta intermedia donde tenía el error (la consulta 2) que creo que es la clave para llegar a solucionar esto.